# How to check one array against another and return the single highest match?

Tags: php, arrays

I have articles on my site that have many different tags. At the moment I am only interested in these 4 tags:

```
Dog
Camel
Bear
Cat
```

If an article has any of these tags I want to display it. If an article has 2 or more of these tags I want the one which is more at the top to be returned. For example if an article has both the Bear and Cat tags, Bear should be returned.

My code so far:

```
function determine_tag($tags) {
    $weights = array(
        'Dog',
        'Camel',
        'Bear',
        'Cat'
    );

    $matches = array();

    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        if(in_array($tag, $weights)) {
            $matches[] = $tag;
        }
    }

    var_dump($matches); // returns array (Cat, Dog)
}

$tags = array('Cat', 'Floating', 'Dog', 'lol', 'Article');
echo determine_tag($tags);
```

I don't think it's very efficient, plus it just returns the matched tags, it doesn't return just the one with the highest weight. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$tag = array_shift(array_intersect($weights, $tags));`

Comment: when applied to my example it returns "Cat", it should return "Dog". I think it assumes the higher the index the higher the weight but it should be seen as reverse.

Answer (score 0):

I would use array_intersect and then just look at the first value in the array of matches. Like this:

```
function determine_tag($tags) {
    $weights = array(
        'Dog',
        'Camel',
        'Bear',
        'Cat'
    );

    $matches = array_intersect($weights, $tags);

    if (count($matches) > 0) {
       $top_match = $matches[0];
    }
}
```